# Add dropdown arrow indicators to menu items that have submenus only?

Tags: css, navigation, html-lists, submenu

I am currently trying to add arrow indicators on my navigation menu for items which have submenu options.

Currently I am using this CSS:

```
.mainNav li > a:after {
   color: #444;
   content: ' ▾';
}
```

But this adds a dropdown arrow to every `<li>` regardless of if there is a submenu or not. Is there a way with just CSS to only add this arrow to items that have sub-items?

Thanks!

Comment: You need JS/Jquery to do this...or maully add a class to the parent `li`

Comment: No. CSS has no `contains child` selector.

Comment: maybe use a before selector instead of an after one?

Comment: @BrianGlaz how will that help?

Comment: what does your HTML for the menu look like?

Comment: The space in `content: ' ▾';` isn't doing you any good. Use the margin or padding css properties if you want cross-browser whitespace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. CSS has no `contains child` selector. You'd probably be better to just add a class to the `li` element. For example:

```
<li class="has-child">
    <a href="#">The Link</a>
    <ul class="child">
        <li>Child 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Your CSS selector would in turn look like:

```
.mainNav li.has-child > a:after {
   color: #444;
   content: ' ▾';
}
```

You could have jQuery add the class for you, if that's an option:

```
$('.mainNav li:has(ul)').addClass('has-child');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TL9pK/)

Comment: Nice! I prefer the ▸ char on `float: right;` though.
And you might want \25B8 to escape it in CSS.

Comment: good but this arrow is not showing in my android device browser (chrome). Why is is so? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

CSS has no `contains child` selector.
However it has various `sibling` selectors, `only-child` and `not(:only-child)`
Since you add indicator to the anchor, use following CSS

```css
 .mainNav li>a:not(:only-child):after {
       color: #444;
       content: ' ▾';
    }
```

```html
<div class="mainNav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">The item with child</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li>Child 1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">No child item</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can without any jQuery : https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/